Proving cluster points for a sequence
I have the sequence $a_n = ⌊\cos(\sqrt{n})⌋, n \in ℕ_0 $, and I have to determine the amount of cluster points. Of course, $\cos(x)$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$, as $x$ varies, and therefore $⌊\cos(\sqrt{n})⌋$ will take on the values $-1, 0$, and $1$ as $n$ grows.
Here is my proof that $-1$ is a cluster point:
For $k =-1$, I have to show that there exists infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $\cos(n) < -\frac{1}{2}$ and also infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $\cos(n)> -\frac{1}{2}$.
Consider $n = (2\pi k + \frac{3π}{2})^2$, for such $n$, $\cos(\sqrt{n})=\cos(2\pi k + \frac{3\pi }{2})=0 $ which is greater than $-\frac{1}{2}$ for infinitely many $k$.
However, I am unable to show that there exists infinitely many natural numbers n such that cos(n)< $-\frac{1}{2}$, and I would appreciate any help.
